# MySQL where in (array)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-in

```
function delete_group($db) {
    $ids = Parameters::get('ids');
    $ids = implode(',', $ids); // now a string like '5,6,7'.
    add_to_log($ids);
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (:ids)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':ids', $ids, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        response('success', 'success', NULL);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        response('error', 'Delete group failed.', NULL);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work: only the first row is deleted. But if I do

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN ($ids)");
```

instead (just insert the string), it works, though the code has the SQL injection security issue. How to make it work and keep secured?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to bind them individually; SQL bound parameters are not arbitrary variable interpolations/concatenations but rather individual values passed in places where accepted.

Comment: If I remember correctly PHP PDO doesn't support `WHERE IN` for prepared statements.  You'll have to do some extra work to get it set up (either create X `?` params depending on the size of the array or do an `implode()` on the array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ids = Parameters::get('ids');
$ids = array_map('intval', $ids);
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
```

Now you don't have to worry about injection.

Comment: This is the best answer from all ones to both questions linked above.

Comment: @noober It may be a short solution, but it is only valid for integer ids. For string values it can be done as well, but it's not recommended to mix bound params and escaped strings in a larger query. Bound params in prepared statements are the accepted best practice even if the line count increases significantly.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Never saw non-integral ids.

Comment: @noober That doesn't mean they don't exist, or that an `IN ()` clause is only ever used on id PK columns.

Comment: Since the comment was "// now a string like '5,6,7'." I'm going to assume they are integers.